# How to get everyday's total order count by sum historical count in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate

Let's say I already have the order count per day in table my_order:

```
2018-10-01 10
2018-10-02 15
2018-10-03 12
2018-10-04 18
2018-10-05 20
```

And I want to got everyday's total count by sum all the historical count just like this:

```
2018-10-01 10
2018-10-02 25
2018-10-03 37
2018-10-04 55
2018-10-05 75
```

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: dbms name please?

Comment: MySQL mostly, but I also want to use it in an internal SQL like internal tool, so not a specific DBMS.

Comment: It matter because `OVER()` will not be available before MySQL 8.  If someone gave you solution with `OVER()`, and you use MySQL 5.7, the solution will be useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of *DBMS* supports window function, so you can do :

```
select m.*, sum(cnt) over (order by date)
from my_order m;
```

If DBMS doesn't have a window functionality then you can use subquery instead :

```
select m.*, (select sum(m1.cnt) from my_order m1 where m1.date <= m.date)
from my_order m;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Levin . . . If this answers your question, you should accept it.